# Deadlock on 2 pages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, deadlock

I'm troubleshooting some deadlocks I'm seeing in a production environment and I'm new to this but something seemed odd to me.  So I have the deadlock graph below:

[image: Deadlock Graph]

The right side of the deadlock is an update that is the following:

```
UPDATE order_sub_line SET sub_line_status = 300 WHERE order_sub_line_id = '75C387EC-A1A7-4587-9FA0-DD33A49009BC'
```

It looks to me in the graph that this update is trying to acquire 2 page locks.  order_sub_line_id is a clustered index.

#### Should this be trying to acquire 2 page locks and if so why?

**Additional Information:**

The deadlock victim is a view (joins a few other tables including order_sub_line) that is essentially running the following query on this table:

```
select top(50) * from order_sub_line osl where osl.sub_line_type = 1 and osl.sub_line_status < 375
```

There are no indexes on order_sub_line besides the clustered primary key index on order_sub_line.order_sub_line_id

**Execution plan:**
[image]

**Deadlock xml:**

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process4224eccf8">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process4224eccf8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:13448 " waittime="1628" ownerId="1683307923" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2013-07-31T08:45:53.157" XDES="0x48afafc40" lockMode="S" schedulerid="2" kpid="1208" status="suspended" spid="151" sbid="0" ecid="15" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2013-07-31T08:45:53.157" lastbatchcompleted="2013-07-31T08:45:53.157" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.157" clientapp="ExactaAOR" hostname="BASTIAN-PC" hostpid="7336" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1683307923" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="72" sqlhandle="0x0200000055b04f0c4d136173c4d51458bdb5002bfe5801370000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
SELECT TOP (@p0)  this_.TRANSPORT_CNTNR_ID as TRANSPORT1_9_0_, this_.CNTNR_NAME as CNTNR2_9_0_, this_.CNTNR_TYPE as CNTNR3_9_0_, this_.CNTNR_HEIGHT as CNTNR4_9_0_, this_.CNTNR_WIDTH as CNTNR5_9_0_, this_.CNTNR_DEPTH as CNTNR6_9_0_, this_.CNTNR_WEIGHT as CNTNR7_9_0_, this_.PARENT_CNTNR_ID as PARENT8_9_0_, this_.RESERVATION_LOC_ID as RESERVAT9_9_0_, this_.WORK_AREA_ID as WORK10_9_0_, this_.WORK_AREA_NAME as WORK11_9_0_, this_.GROUP_ID as GROUP12_9_0_, this_.RELEASE_STATUS as RELEASE13_9_0_, this_.RELEASE_TIME as RELEASE14_9_0_, this_.PRINT_STATUS as PRINT15_9_0_, this_.SUB_LINE_COUNT as SUB16_9_0_, this_.ORDER_ID as ORDER17_9_0_, this_.QTY_REQUESTED as QTY18_9_0_, this_.ORDER_NAME as ORDER19_9_0_, this_.ORDER_PRIORITY as ORDER20_9_0_, this_.ORDER_STATUS as ORDER21_9_0_, this_.ON_HOLD as ON22_9_0_, this_.DUE_DATE as DUE23_9_0_, this_.ORDER_SUB_LINE_STATUS as ORDER24_9_0_ FROM V_CARTON_RELEASE this_ WHERE (this_.RELEASE_STATUS = @p1 and this_.ORDER_SUB_LINE_STATUS &lt; @p2) ORDER BY this_.RELEASE_TIME asc     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(4000),@p2 int)SELECT TOP (@p0)  this_.TRANSPORT_CNTNR_ID as TRANSPORT1_9_0_, this_.CNTNR_NAME as CNTNR2_9_0_, this_.CNTNR_TYPE as CNTNR3_9_0_, this_.CNTNR_HEIGHT as CNTNR4_9_0_, this_.CNTNR_WIDTH as CNTNR5_9_0_, this_.CNTNR_DEPTH as CNTNR6_9_0_, this_.CNTNR_WEIGHT as CNTNR7_9_0_, this_.PARENT_CNTNR_ID as PARENT8_9_0_, this_.RESERVATION_LOC_ID as RESERVAT9_9_0_, this_.WORK_AREA_ID as WORK10_9_0_, this_.WORK_AREA_NAME as WORK11_9_0_, this_.GROUP_ID as GROUP12_9_0_, this_.RELEASE_STATUS as RELEASE13_9_0_, this_.RELEASE_TIME as RELEASE14_9_0_, this_.PRINT_STATUS as PRINT15_9_0_, this_.SUB_LINE_COUNT as SUB16_9_0_, this_.ORDER_ID as ORDER17_9_0_, this_.QTY_REQUESTED as QTY18_9_0_, this_.ORDER_NAME as ORDER19_9_0_, this_.ORDER_PRIORITY as ORDER20_9_0_, this_.ORDER_STATUS as ORDER21_9_0_, this_.ON_HOLD as ON22_9_0_, this_.DUE_DATE as DUE23_9_0_, this_.ORDER_SUB_LINE_STATUS as ORDER24_9_0_ FROM V_CARTON_RELEASE this_ WHERE (this_.RELEASE_STATUS = @p1 and this_.ORDER_SUB_LINE_STATUS &lt; @p2) ORDER    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process4bf7bdc38" taskpriority="0" logused="8608" waitresource="PAGE: 7:1:13447 " waittime="1616" ownerId="1683308190" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2013-07-31T08:45:53.450" XDES="0x4ebd456a8" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="1" kpid="6032" status="suspended" spid="85" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2013-07-31T08:45:53.450" lastbatchcompleted="2013-07-31T08:45:53.450" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.450" clientapp="ExactaAOR" hostname="BASTIAN-PC" hostpid="7336" loginname="asapdb" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1683308190" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="60" sqlhandle="0x02000000109639184c42e35fa55701e017640d83bd4818c30000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE ORDER_SUB_LINE SET SUB_LINE_STATUS = @p0 WHERE ORDER_SUB_LINE_ID = @p1     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@p0 int,@p1 uniqueidentifier)UPDATE ORDER_SUB_LINE SET SUB_LINE_STATUS = @p0 WHERE ORDER_SUB_LINE_ID = @p1    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="13448" dbid="7" subresource="FULL" objectname="Exactadb.dbo.order_sub_line" id="lock4cf017000" mode="IX" associatedObjectId="72057594460962816">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process4bf7bdc38" mode="IX"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process4224eccf8" mode="S" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="13447" dbid="7" subresource="FULL" objectname="Exactadb.dbo.order_sub_line" id="lock4a4554500" mode="S" associatedObjectId="72057594460962816">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process4224eccf8" mode="S"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process4bf7bdc38" mode="IX" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

Comment: What does the execution plan look like?  Is there a key/index lookup?

Comment: Remember that the clustered index is stored as a b-tree and the update will have to navigate from the root node, through any intermediate levels and to the leaf node. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @AdamHaines I've posted the execution plan

Comment: You need to post the actual deadlock XML, not the picture.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Added the xml

Comment: I just want to confirm the the clustered index is a unique primary key and no duplicates rows are present, correct?

Comment: @AdamHaines It's a guid column and it is set to the primary key

Comment: I have been trying to reproduce the issue and cannot find an exact match to your situation.  The reasons you typically see this is forwarded records in heaps, page splits, or off row lobs, which do not seem to apply to your situation.  I am starting to think there is something that we are missing.  Do you have an UPDATE trigger on the table?

Comment: @AdamHaines There are several triggers on that table. 4 different ones on update actually.  That's a good point.  It looks like some of them are doing selects on that table.

Comment: @Cole : Did you find any root cause ? We are also facing the same scenario, however in our case one process has insert and other update with where having clustered primary index clause

Comment: @GautamTadigoppula Your case sounds a little different but I would recommend 2 things that commonly fix deadlocks for me. 1 is to make sure you are updating by primary key and to order your updates / inserts by this value so you are always updating things in the same order.  2 is to make sure you have non clustered indexes on all your foreign key fields otherwise updates and inserts end up doing table scans.  See this for an example of how unordered updates can cause a deadlock: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175257/maintaining-order-of-updates-across-transactions-to-avoid-deadlocks

Answer (score 2):

The following inferences made from the data provided,

1. Both the transactions are running under read committed isolation level.
2. One transaction is doing multiple individual row UPDATEs. This is evident from the fact that one of the process is holding an IX lock and waiting for another. As per the execution plan, the UPDATE statement is using a single row clustered index seek. So it will be acquiring an X lock at the KEY level and an IX lock at the page level.
3. The SELECT statement and is acquiring locks at PAGE level granularity. Also the SELECT is retaining the locks after reading the pages. Under normal circumstances in READ COMMITTED ISOLATION LEVEL, a SELECT statement will acquire and release SHARED locks immediately after reading.

With these findings, I am almost certain that the deadlock is happening due to a special scenario involving a query optimization called UNORDERED PREFETCH. This is the only scenario I am aware of where SELECT statements running under READ COMMITTED Isolation level retains the SHARED locks until the end of the statement.

A repro and possible resolutions to this this type of deadlock can be found at 
https://web.archive.org/web/20120806214319/http://sqlindian.com/2012/07/13/deadlock-on-select-due-to-unordered-prefetch/